# Excel-Java(Apache POI): Store Variable Value of Current Workbook to Another Variable of Another Workbook

Tags: java, excel

Yo guys, My program runs this way:

I have a specific data from a workbook and I want to transfer that specific data to another workbook using Java-Excel(Apache POI). So I stored the cell location of that specific data to a variable. Now, I am trying to set the value of that variable to another variable which is located to another workbook. But the program doesn't transfer the data to another workbook and It just reads every row of data and prints it in output panel in eclipse **Could you guys help me out? Could you find my error? Thanks in advance.**

```
   // get the workbook Data
    Workbook wbRES = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\input.xls"));
    Workbook wbML = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\output.xls"));

    // get the sheet from Output
    Sheet sheetRESEARCH = wbRES.getSheet("Data");
    Sheet sheetML = wbML.getSheet("Output");

    try
    {
        // initialize variables
        int iRowCountDataRES = 1;
        Cell cPostDateRES = null;
        Cell cPostDateML = null;
        Row rPostDateRES;
        Row rPostDateML;

        // loop thru every row of data in Data Sheet
        while (sheetRESEARCH.getRow(iRowCountDataRES) != null)
        {
            //set the cell location in Data Sheet
            rPostDateRES = sheetRESEARCH.getRow(iRowCountDataRES);
            cPostDateRES = rPostDateRES.getCell(0);

            //set the cell location in Output Sheet
            rPostDateML = sheetML.createRow(iRowCountDataRES);
            cPostDateML = rPostDateML.createCell(0);

            //transfer data to Output Sheet
            cPostDateML.setCellValue(cPostDateRES.getRichStringCellValue().toString());

            //print cell value
            System.out.println(cPostDateRES.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
            //cPostDateRES.getRichStringCellValue().toString();

            //increment row value
            iRowCountDataRES = iRowCountDataRES + 1;
        }

    }

    catch(Exception e)
    {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    wbML.close();
    wbRES.close();
```

Comment: Did you try to run it through the debugger to see what's happening?

Comment: As always: "But the program doesn't work." => Please explain what exactly you expected, and what happened instead.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose I want to transfer a specific data to another workbook. It just reads every row of data and prints it in output panel in eclipse.

Comment: After the while loop, do you write your created workbook to an OutputStream (eg. a file)?

Comment: @ZaidMalhis Nope. I tried to put OutputStream but it transfers all the data to another workbook. I only need the specific data to be transferred.

Comment: Show your full code please.

Comment: @VictorPolevoy Yeah. It prints all the read cell contents and then terminates the loop after reading an empty cell.

Comment: Hi guys I've posted my entire code above. Please take a look at it. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for all your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to write your Workbook to an OutputStream, how do you expect the changes to be saved if you don't write them?

Code:

```
// get the workbook Data
Workbook wbRES = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\input.xls"));
Workbook wbML = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileInputStream("C:\\output.xls"));
// get the sheet from Output
Sheet sheetRESEARCH = wbRES.getSheet("Data");
Sheet sheetML = wbML.getSheet("Output");

try
{
    // initialize variables
    int iRowCountDataRES = 1;
    Cell cPostDateRES = null;
    Cell cPostDateML = null;
    Row rPostDateRES;
    Row rPostDateML;

    // loop thru every row of data in Data Sheet
    while (sheetRESEARCH.getRow(iRowCountDataRES) != null)
    {
        //set the cell location in Data Sheet
        rPostDateRES = sheetRESEARCH.getRow(iRowCountDataRES);
        cPostDateRES = rPostDateRES.getCell(0);

        //set the cell location in Output Sheet
        rPostDateML = sheetML.createRow(iRowCountDataRES);
        cPostDateML = rPostDateML.createCell(0);

        //transfer data to Output Sheet
        cPostDateML.setCellValue(cPostDateRES.getRichStringCellValue().toString());

        //print cell value
        System.out.println(cPostDateRES.getRichStringCellValue().toString());
        //cPostDateRES.getRichStringCellValue().toString();

        //increment row value
        iRowCountDataRES = iRowCountDataRES + 1;
    }
    //add this line and do a proper exception handling and Close the OutputStream and workbooks in a finally block
    wbML.write( new FileOutputStream("C:\\output.xls"));
}

catch(Exception e)
{

    e.printStackTrace();
}
wbML.close();
wbRES.close();
```

Comment: Thanks man! Appreciate it. Now I know how FileOutputStream works. Have a great day.

Comment: You too :). Don't forget to Close your OutputStream and workbooks in a finally block and to do a proper exception handling.